# IIS ARR Load Balancer Set up, How do I access my sites now?

Tags: asp.net, iis, load-balancing, arr

I've set up a load balancer using ARR on my server. 
 I have two content servers that are hosting the web application and its API. Individually I am able to access the websites.

I've added the servers to a new Server Farm, I've given it a name as well.
Now, here comes the catch.
I don't have a DNS assigned to the server IP.

I'm not sure how to access the web sites through the load balancer. Is there a port on the server on which the farm works? or a URL?